# Script moving AD Info to excel, Is there a way to write an if function for description values?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

new with PowerShell here and I'm trying to write a script to move some AD info over to excel through powershell. The problem I'm having is that all other things aside, I am trying to have one of the fields in excel be the description fields. From there I am trying to write an if function to filter based on if it fits a description or not.

````
get-aduser -Filter * -properties CN,PasswordNeverExpires,LastLogon,description| where {
$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq "true" } | If ( $_.description -eq "super") {"SU"} Else {"Human"} | Select-Object CN, enabled,samAccountName,LastLogon, description | Export-Csv $path ```

No error message just doesn't display description field in excel.
````

Comment: `if`/`else` cannot be used on the pipeline the way you are trying.  What exactly are you hoping it will do?

Comment: ah, I'm trying to take the description and if it matches a certain description have it put a certain word in excel. If that makes sense

Comment: You mean you want a new column in your CSV with either 'SU' or 'Human' as it's value?  What would the column be called (i.e. the header)?  You should look at [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6) and [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-6).  You can probably do something directly with `Select-Object`, but I think it would be messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the value for `description` in the `select`-block. No need to do it in the pipe. Here is how you do it with a [calculated property](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx). A calculated property is a property that is defined as a hashtable with a name ("description") and a codeblock with the expression (if/else):

```
get-aduser -Filter * -properties CN,PasswordNeverExpires,LastLogon,description| where {
$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq "true" } | select CN, enabled,samAccountName,LastLogon,@{Name ="description";Expression={ If ( $_.description -eq "super") {"SU"} Else {"Human"}  }} | Export-Csv $path
```